# Get the value of second dimension in numpy array

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, numpy

My NumPy array looks like this

```
  array([-5.65998629e-02, -1.21844731e-01,  2.44745120e-01,  1.73819885e-01,
         -1.99641913e-01, -9.42866057e-02, ..])]
 ['آؤ_بھگت'
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., ..])                       ]
 ['آؤلی'
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0..])                       ]
```

When I want to search some specific word I use the built in function

```
arr_index = np.where(x == 'شعلہ_مزاجی')
print(arr_index)

print(x[arr_index])
```

When I print it gives the index, but not the second value

How to get the second value in numpy array?

Comment: Hi Abdul, this question might be relevant for this Stack Exchange, as it is more implementation. 
However, happy to answer:
Essentially looking at the structure, I would say: `x[arr_index][1]` if the second value in the numpy array refers to the one-hot encoding-looking vector.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I have tried it but it give me the error

"IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"
  I want to fetch the embedding matrix but I could not by calling the numpy fnctions

Comment: When I print (x.ndim)) it gives me 2 , but when I want to print x[arr_index][1] it gives me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

I was not getting the actual index value and it will also not print if the second value does not have any encodings.

```
arr_index = np.where(x == 'یے')

print(len(arr_index))

value = (arr_index[0])
print(value)

result = str(value)[1:-1]

result = int(result)

value = x[(result)][1]

print(value)
```

This will give the embeddings